# Changing User permissions - Seagate Hard Drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, permission

All of a sudden, my hard drive has stopped working. I can only view its contents but can't store anything new now. I also can't change its permissions. What is the issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a third-party utility like NTFS-3G, OS X can't write to NTFS formatted hard drives. Did you reformat the disk recently or reinstall OS X?

Comment: No, I didn't. I might have reformatted the disk, don't remember doing so though. Didn't reinstall OS X. Any fix now?

Comment: @HPV Get MacFUSE and NTFS-3g.

Comment: Installed both and restarted. Got the following error. `NTFS-3G could not mount /dev/disk1s1
at /Volumes/Expansion Drive because the following problem occurred:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfuse.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: Now , I can't see my hard drive in finder but here http://cl.ly/2l3312112k2c0Q013x3T

Comment: You should ask a new question about that - it's been awhile since I used MacFUSE or NTFS-3g and I'd never gotten that error. Sorry. If you uninstall the two, will the disk mount again?

Comment: Uninstalled, I can now see the drive in the finder like previously.

Comment: I installed the new version of NTFS-3g only for Lion and its working. Thanks!